# Rlang: how to treat strings as symbols

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

Once again I'm baffled by the documentation of `rlang` and the error messages. I've tried 20 different iterations of this using double and triple bangs, `:=`, `quo`, `enquo`, `ensym`, and every other unclearly named rlang function.

IF you sense frustration it's because every single time I try to use `rlang` to deal with variables for object names I run into the same wall.  Am I missing something critical? Am I stupid? Is the `rlang` function names and documentation just really poor?

I'm trying to determine the class of a variable in a `tibble`.  In addition to help with doing this, I would be grateful if someone could suggestion how I would have found the answer to this in the documentation.

```r
require(tidyverse)
require(rlang)

x <- enframe(names(mtcars), name = NULL, value = "var") %>% 
  add_column(df = "mtcars")

x %>% mutate(cls = class(sym(paste0(df, "$", var))))
#> Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `x %>% mutate(cls = class(eval(parse(text = paste0(df, "$", var)))))`?

Comment: @Matt doesn't work as expected.  mtcars2 <-  mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl))
x <- enframe(names(mtcars), name = NULL, value = "var") %>% 
  add_column(df = "mtcars2")
x %>% mutate(cls = class(eval(parse(text = paste0(df, "$", var)))))

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `rowwise`, it should work if you add that in`x %>% rowwise %>% mutate(cls = class(eval(parse(text = paste0(df, "$", var)))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Parse and evaluate it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

x %>% rowwise %>% mutate(cls = class(eval_tidy(parse_expr(paste0(df, "$", var)))))
```

**2)** or use `sym` from rlang and `pull` from purrr

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

x %>% rowwise %>% mutate(cls = class(pull(eval_tidy(sym(df)), var)))
```

**3)** or base R function `get` to retrieve `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% rowwise %>% mutate(cls = class(get(df)[[var]]))
```

Comment: Note that if you want to stick with tidyverse in (3) you can use `env_get(environment(), df, inherit = TRUE)` in place of `get(df)`